# How to allow the view to go beyong device dimensions - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want my view to be of a the definite width and height as I want regardless of the device's dimensions. But I don't want to put it inside a ScrollView. I don't care if the view is cut or not. Just that it should take up the space as much it wants.
I want it to go beyond the device screen dimensions.
I tried the following code so far :

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

but my view is still trapped inside the device's screen.
How can I achieve it ?

Comment: "width and height as I want" vs. "space as much it wants". How big is your view really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My view was not actually trapped inside the device but the root view was starting from the top of the device's screen only. So I gave **negative margin** to my **root view** and hardcoded it in the xml of my root view. And it worked.